# How to save streaming data to InfluxDB?

Tags: database, streaming, influxdb

I am trying to save data as it arrives in a streaming fashion (with the least amount of delay) to my database which is InfluxDB. Currently I save it in batches.

**Current setup - interval based**

Currently I have an Airflow instance where I read the data from a REST API every 5min and then save it to the InfluxDB.

**Desired setup - continuous**

Instead of saving data every 5 min, I would like to establish a connection via a Web-socket (I guess) and save the data as it arrives. I have never done this before and I am confusing how actually it is done? Some question I have are:

- One I write the code for it, do I keep it up like a daemon?
- Do I need to use something like Telegraf for this or that's not really the case ([example article](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-streaming-data-into-influxdb/))
- Instead of Airflow (since it is for batch processing) do I need to use something like Apache Beam or Spark?

As you can see, I am quite lost on where to start, what to read and how to make sense from all this. Any advise on direction and/or guidance for a set-up would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't know whether InfluxDB supports data streaming, but you can stream Influx line protocol data over a single http connection to VictoriaMetrics. See [these docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#how-to-send-data-from-influxdb-compatible-agents-such-as-telegraf) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are keen to code a java service which would process the incoming data, so one of the solution is to implement a websocket with for example [jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html).

From there you receive the data in json format for example and you process the data using the [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) framework with which you fill the database. Influxdb-java will allow you to create and manage the data.

I don't know airflow, and how you produce the data, so maybe there is built-in tools (influxdb sinks) that can save you some work in your context.

I hope that this can give you some guide lines to start digging more.